# Python - recursion not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, pycharm

I have a following code:

```
d = {'init':
       [{'solve':
                 [{'subsolve':
                       [{'vals': [{'Blade summary': 'asdf'},
                                  {'Blade summary': 'fdsa'}]}]},
                  {'subsolve':
                       [{'vals': [{'Blade summary': 'ffff'}]}]}]},
        {'solve':
                 [{'subsolve':
                       [{'vals': 'bbbb'}]}]}]}

def parseDics(lst, mainReg):
    print('call')
    for dic in lst:
        for key, vals in dic.items():
            if key == mainReg:
                if mainReg == 'vals':
                    yield vals
                parseDics(vals, 'vals')
            else:
                parseDics(vals, mainReg)



if __name__=='__main__':
    pp.pprint(list(parseDics(d['init'], 'solve')))
```

The function itself is not complete, but that's not a problem for now. The problem is, it appears, that recursive calls don't work.

If I try to run it now, I'll get only this output:

```
call
[]
```

So the function was called only once. When I try to step into the nested function call (I'm using PyCharm), then I'm simply not not able to and the function call is "over-stepped".

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't my function called recursively?

Comment: `yield from parseDics(vals, 'vals')`?

Comment: Your code only checks if the key is `solve` or `vals`, it will never recurse into the dictionary items that have `subsolve` as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually do something with the result of your recursive calls. Since you're using `yield` with the value, you probably need to use it there too.

Answer (score 2):

`parseDics` isn't a regular function, it's a generator. So you need to call it like a generator, rather than a regular function, otherwise it won't work. The first call works because when you call `list(parseDicts(...))`, the list constructor is calling `parseDicts` as a generator. But within `parseDicts`, you try to recursively call `parseDicts` as a function, which doesn't work.

Change the recursive calls to use `yield from` if you are using Python 3.3+:

```
def parseDics(lst, mainReg):
    print('call')
    for dic in lst:
        for key, vals in dic.items():
            if key == mainReg:
                if mainReg == 'vals':
                    yield vals
                yield from parseDics(vals, 'vals')
            else:
                yield from parseDics(vals, mainReg)
```

For older versions of Python, you would need to iterate over those recursive calls and yield each value that generate:

```
def parseDics(lst, mainReg):
    print('call')
    for dic in lst:
        for key, vals in dic.items():
            if key == mainReg:
                if mainReg == 'vals':
                    yield vals
                for val in parseDics(vals, 'vals'):
                    yield val
            else:
                for val in parseDics(vals, mainReg):
                    yield val
```

Calling a generator as a function merely creates the generator, it doesn't run it. E.g.:

```
>>> def my_gen():
    print("my_gen()")
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        yield i

>>> my_gen()
<generator object my_gen at 0x00000000045B6B48>

>>> list(my_gen())
my_gen()
0
1
2
3
4
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.4 you can use `yield from parseDics(vals, 'vals')`, for Python 2:

```
for val in parseDics(vals, 'vals'):
    yield val
```